# Where is my Common Wire?

Tags: furnace, thermostat, thermostat-c-wire

I purchased a wifi thermostat and cannot located the common wire. My unit is old and is a Coleman 70 with no terminals inside labeling the wires. 
[image: wiring diagram]
[image: wires]

As you can see in the second image, there is a blue wire that is not being used that goes to my thermostat. I am trying to use this as a common wire, I am just unable to determine where this wire connects to.

THank you for the help.

Answer (score 2):

I've highlighted the `C` wire for you in the schematic.

[image: Highlighted c wire]

And in the actual wiring

[image: Highlighted c wire]